# The youtube API sometimes throws error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object

Tags: youtube-api, php

When i launch the php script, sometime works fine, but many other times it retrieve me this errror

> Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in
>   /membri/americanhorizon/ytvideo/rilevametadatadaurlyoutube.php on line
>   21

This is the first part of the code

```
// set feed URL
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dZec2Lbr_r8';

// read feed into SimpleXML object
$entry = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

$video = parseVideoEntry($entry);


function parseVideoEntry($entry) {      
  $obj= new stdClass;

  // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
  $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'); //<----this is the doomed line 21
```

UPDATE: solution adopted

```
   for ($i=0 ; $i< count($fileArray); $i++)
  {

    // set feed URL
    $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$fileArray[$i];


    // read feed into SimpleXML object
    $entry = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);


   if (is_object($entry))
   {
       $video = parseVideoEntry($entry);

       echo ($video->description."|".$video->length);
       echo "<br>";
    }
     else
     {
       $i--;
     }

 }
```

In this mode i force the script to re-check the file that caused the error

Comment: Could be a timeout issue as it is happening intermittently.

Comment: the error is retrieved istantanely after the launch of the script, so it's not a timeout problem..farther, i've taken this piece of code from the official documentation page

Comment: ohh you can try yourself the script

http://americanhorizon.altervista.org/rilevametadatadaurlyoutube.php

Comment: @h2ooooo: var_dump retrieve me bool(false) when the error happen

Comment: @AnnaLica Then it might be a problem from YouTube if it's not a timeout. False is equal to failure: "`or FALSE on failure.`". If you want to get more accurate details, then use cURL to get the data, and `simplexml_load_string($outputFromCurlExec);` to turn it into XML.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sometimes? Really?
Take a look at this:

```
<?php

$dummy; //IN FACT, this var is NULL now

// Will throw exactly the same error you get
$dummy->children();
```

Why? Because, we can call method from an object type.

So, if you wanna avoid errors like this one, next time you would call the method ensure that it's "possible".

```
<?php

if ( is_object($dummy) && method_exists($dummy, 'children') ){
   //sure it works
   $dummy->children();
}
```

Comment: GREAT!!!
According to your suggestion i've adopted a genial solution.. If the variabile isn't a ojject, i force to re-check it!
I update my first post for share the code

Answer (score 2):

You are first of all calling a function:

```
$entry = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
```

That function has a return value. You find it documented on the manual page of that function:

- http://php.net/simplexml_load_file

Then you use that return value in form of a variable `$entry` without verifying that the function call was successful.

Because of that, you run into an error next. However *your* error/mistake is how you treat the return value of the function.

Not dealing with return values properly is like calling for trouble. Read about the function you use, check the return value(s) and proceed according to success or error conditions.

```
$entry = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

if (FALSE === $entry)
{
    // youtube not available.
}
else 
{
    // that's what I love!
}
```

Comment: Uhm the problem sound like that the funcion is launched before che call is completed.. So i need some listener that tell me wehen the call completes. Right?

Comment: Sort of. You have the "listener" already, it is the return value in `$entry`. So the call will always complete, but the outcome is not always positive. As you are loading data from a remote service, this can just happen, e.g. network error and similar. Imagine that service with youtube is down because of a database problem on their end. So you need to design for error. Like checking if the function result is false.

Comment: So, seems a youtube problem :(